# Is there an easy way to remove unnecessary whitespaces inside of brackets that are in the middle of a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, whitespace, brackets

I've strings in the form of:

```py
s = "Wow that is really nice, ( 2.1 ) shows that according to the drawings in ( 1. 1) and a) there are errors."
```

and I would like to get a cleaned string in the form of:

```py
s = "Wow that is really nice, (2.1) shows that according to the drawings in (1.1) and a) there are errors."
```

I tried to fix it with regex:

```py
import re

regex = r" (?=[^(]*\))"
s = "Wow that is really nice, ( 2.1 ) shows that according to the drawings in ( 1. 1) and a) there are some errors."
re.sub(regex, "", s)
```

But I get faulty results like this:
`Wow that is really nice, (2.1) shows that according to the drawings in (1.1)anda) there are some errors.`

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem when you don't always have the same number of opening and closing brackets?

Comment: How do you decide which whitespaces are unecessary? If you have a sentence in parentheneses should those whitespace get removed as well?

Comment: With my data it will not be the case that whole sentences are inside the brackets. But hypothetically, if that's the case, then yes.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about that, but you can try to do the following:

```
s = s.replace('( ','(')
s = s.replace(' )',')')
```

Here replace(old, new) is standard function, that replace old string to the new one. I hope it will help.

Comment: Does not work on inner space in `( 1. 1)`.

Comment: yeah, that is going to be messy. But you can change that one as well with replace function. by setting old string as ". ", and new one as ".".      
That should look like this ` s = s.replace(". ", ".")`

Comment: That'd remove all spaces after . at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If the only whitespace you want to remove are the ones that occur directly after an opening bracket (or before a closing), then a simple string [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) might work:

```
>>> s.replace("( ", "(").replace(" )", ")")
'Wow that is really nice, (2.1) shows that according to the drawings in (1. 1) and a) there are errors.'
```

Comment: Based on the expected result, inner space in `( 1. 1)` needs to be removed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can match all the inner-most parentheneses with simple regex, and then perform a substitution on the matches to remove all the whitespaces.

```
import re
s = "Wow that is really nice, ( 2.1 ) shows that according to the drawings in ( 1. 1) and a) there are errors."
regex = r"\([^\(\)]*\)"
res = re.sub(regex, lambda s: s[0].replace(" ", ""), s)

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 r" (?=[^()]*\))"
```

This excludes 'close parenthesis' from the things that can be inside a pair of parentheses.

Whether this works will depends whether you have nested brackets in your text.

Nested brackets is not something that can be solved with regex- you need a parser (it may need to count the brackets)

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to match balanced parenthesis and remove the spaces, you can make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and a recursive pattern

```
\([^)(]*+(?:(?R)[^)(]*)*+\)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LzrN5T/1).

**Note** that it will remove all spaces.

```
import regex

pattern = r"\([^)(]*+(?:(?R)[^)(]*)*+\)"

s = ("Wow that is really nice, ( 2.1 ) shows that according to the drawings in ( 1. 1) and a) there are errors.\n"
"Wow that is really nice, ( 2.1 (2.1 ( 1,3 ) ) )shows that according to the drawings in ( 1. 1) and a) there are errors.")

print(regex.sub(pattern, lambda m: m[0].replace(" ", ""), s))
```

Output

```
Wow that is really nice, (2.1) shows that according to the drawings in (1.1) and a) there are errors.
Wow that is really nice, (2.1(2.1(1,3)))shows that according to the drawings in (1.1) and a) there are errors.
```

---

To only remove the spaces after the `(` and before the `)`

```
import regex

pattern = r"\([^)(]*+(?:(?R)[^)(]*)*+\)"

s = "Wow that is really nice, ( test in 2.1 (2.1 test( 1,3 test ) ) )shows that according to the drawings in ( 1. 1) and a) there are errors."

print(regex.sub(pattern, lambda m: regex.sub(r"(?<=\() +| +(?=\))", "", m[0]), s))
```

Output

```
Wow that is really nice, (test in 2.1 (2.1 test(1,3 test)))shows that according to the drawings in (1. 1) and a) there are errors.
```